# How to pull in creative fields data from Facebook API to google spreadsheet?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

```
function fetchFacebookAdsData() {const accessToken = 'accesstokenkey';const adAccountId = 'acount-id';const apiUrl1 = https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/act_${adAccountId}/ads?fields=account_id,id,name,creative{id,name,status,object_story_id,object_story_spec,thumbnail_url,image_url,title},insights.fields(impressions,spend,reach)&level=ad&date_preset=last_14d&time_increment=14;const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl1);const data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()).data;const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();for (const ad of data) {sheet.appendRow([ad.account_id,ad.id,ad.name,ad.creative.id,ad.creative.name,ad.creative.thumbnail_url,ad.creative.image_url,ad.insights.fields.impressions,ad.insights.fields.spend]);}}
```

when I try to pull the data to the spreadsheet getting the following error
function fetchFacebookAdsData() {const accessToken = 'accesstokenkey';const adAccountId = 'acount-id';const apiUrl1 = [https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/act_${adAccountId}/ads?fields=account_id,id,name,creative{id,name,status,object_story_id,object_story_spec,thumbnail_url,image_url,title},insights.fields(impressions,spend,reach)&level=ad&date_preset=last_14d&time_increment=14;const](https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/act_$%7BadAccountId%7D/ads?fields=account_id,id,name,creative%7Bid,name,status,object_story_id,object_story_spec,thumbnail_url,image_url,title%7D,insights.fields(impressions,spend,reach)&level=ad&date_preset=last_14d&time_increment=14;const) response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl1);const data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()).data;const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();for (const ad of data) {sheet.appendRow([ad.account_id,ad.id,ad.name,ad.creative.id,ad.creative.name,ad.creative.thumbnail_url,ad.creative.image_url,ad.insights.fields.impressions,ad.insights.fields.spend]);}}
Exception: Invalid argument: [https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/act_1121111/ads?fields=account_id,id,name,creative{id,name,status,object_story_id,object_story_spec,thumbnail_url,image_url,title},insights.fields(impressions,spend,reach)&level=ad&date_preset=last_14d&time_increment=14](https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/act_1121111/ads?fields=account_id,id,name,creative%7Bid,name,status,object_story_id,object_story_spec,thumbnail_url,image_url,title%7D,insights.fields(impressions,spend,reach)&level=ad&date_preset=last_14d&time_increment=14)